# OpenLayers - How to validate whether the BBOX strategy works successfully?

Tags: openlayers

I want to send requests to our feature server that asks only data within
the viewable map extent. So I've used BBOX strategy and HTTP Protocol as
following code.

```
    mVectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: 'http://localhost:56786/jlist.geojson',
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'read': myReadFunction,
                'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            })
        }),
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
    });
```

I've added a feature outside the viewable map to the geojson file shown at below.

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [29.0, 41.060]},
        "properties": {"name": "IST J1", "img": "img/marker.png"}
      },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [29.0, 41.100]},
        "properties": {"name": "IST J2", "img": "img/marker.png"}
      },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [59.0, 41.100]},
        "properties": {"name": "IST J3", "img": "img/marker.png"}
      }
  ]
}
```

To validate, I've added an alert to the function myReadFunction which shows
the json string. But the alert shows all features in geojson file. I
suppose our feature server sends all geojson content instead of viewable
features? How can I validate or observe whether the BBOX strategy works successfully?

```
        function myReadFunction(json, type, filter) {
            alert("json: " + json);

            type = (type) ? type : "FeatureCollection";
            var results = null;
            var obj = null;
            if (typeof json == "string") {
                obj = OpenLayers.Format.JSON.prototype.read.apply(this, [json, filter]);
            } else {
                obj = json;
            }
            if (!obj) {
                OpenLayers.Console.error("Bad JSON: " + json);
            } else if (typeof (obj.type) != "string") {
                OpenLayers.Console.error("Bad GeoJSON - no type: " + json);
            } else if (this.isValidType(obj, type)) {
                switch (type) {
                    case "Geometry":
                        try {
                            results = this.parseGeometry(obj);
                        } catch (err) {
                            OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Feature":
                        try {
                            results = this.parseFeature(obj);
                            results.type = "Feature";
                        } catch (err) {
                            OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "FeatureCollection":
                        // for type FeatureCollection, we allow input to be any type
                        results = [];
                        switch (obj.type) {
                            case "Feature":
                                try {
                                    results.push(this.parseFeature(obj));
                                } catch (err) {
                                    results = null;
                                    OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                                }
                                break;
                            case "FeatureCollection":
                                for (var i = 0, len = obj.features.length; i < len; ++i) {
                                    try {results.push(this.parseFeature(obj.features[i]));
                                    } catch (err) {
                                        results = null;
                                        OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                try {
                                    var geom = this.parseGeometry(obj);
                                    results.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geom));
                                } catch (err) {
                                    results = null;
                                    OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                                }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            return results;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your helps and explanations,
Yasemin

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like firebug in Firefox you can see all page requests in the 'Net' tab. You can see which parameters are transmitted (your bounds) and offcourse the result set. That way you can check if your server response is OK.

But you should know that the BBOX has a ratio. This is the factor by which the bounds are extended, so the ratio of the data bounds to the viewport bounds. The default is 2! Thus if your test feature is just outside the viewport, it will be in the requested bbox.

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html#OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX.ratio